# Use sata splitters in a software RAID setup?

Tags: raid, sata, nas

I'm looking at setting up NAS using FreeNAS. I'm working on a parts list that would be that NAS system. I'm looking at the MiniITX motherboard form factor for compact-ness. The big down side is that motherboards of that size only have 1 or 2 sata ports. Can I use sata (data) splitters to allow more drives to be connected with functioning software RAID? I understand that using splitters will reduce the throughput of each drive. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While port multipliers do exist for SATA, however you have to purchase hardware to support it, if your motherboard does not.

On top of that, recent [tests](http://www.zdnet.com/article/are-sata-port-multipliers-safe/) show that they are not safe for RAID environments.